Micronaut Native Image
I'm trying to compile a micronaut 4.6 application with pubsub and kafka libraries to a native image using the provided micronaut gradle aot task. The build breaks on bitbucket with the following error. What can I do to help the GraalVM with building the image. If additional information is needed, I will write it down.

[0m[91mWarning: Could not resolve class
org.hamcrest.number.OrderingComparison for reflection configuration.
Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.hamcrest.number.OrderingComparison.
[0m[91mWarning: Could not resolve class
org.osgi.framework.BundleEvent for reflection configuration. Reason:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.BundleEvent.
[0m[91mWarning: Method
ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.JsonFormatter.valueOf(String) not found.
Warning: Method ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.valueOf(String) not
found.
Warning: Method ch.qos.logback.core.Layout.valueOf(String) not found.
Warning: Method
ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingPolicy.valueOf(String) not found.
Warning: Method
ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TriggeringPolicy.valueOf(String) not
found.
Warning: Method ch.qos.logback.core.spi.ContextAware.valueOf(String)
not found.
[0m[91mWarning: Could not resolve class
reactor.core.publisher.Traces$StackWalkerCallSiteSupplierFactory for
reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
reactor.core.publisher.Traces$StackWalkerCallSiteSupplierFactory.
Warning: Could not resolve class
reactor.core.publisher.Traces$ExceptionCallSiteSupplierFactory for
reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
reactor.core.publisher.Traces$ExceptionCallSiteSupplierFactory.
[0m[91mWarning: Could not resolve class
io.opencensus.impl.trace.TraceComponentImpl for reflection
configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
io.opencensus.impl.trace.TraceComponentImpl.
[0m[91mWarning: Could not resolve class
io.opencensus.impl.metrics.MetricsComponentImpl for reflection
configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
io.opencensus.impl.metrics.MetricsComponentImpl.
[0m[91mWarning: Could not resolve class
com.google.auth.appengine.AppEngineCredentials for reflection
configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.google.auth.appengine.AppEngineCredentials.
[0m[91mWarning: Could not resolve class
org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.DefaultEvictionPolicy for reflection
configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.DefaultEvictionPolicy.
[0m[1/8] Initializing...
(19.0s @ 0.38GB) Java version: 17.0.9+9, vendor version: GraalVM CE
17.0.9+9.1 Graal compiler: optimization level: 2, target machine: x86-64-v3 C compiler: gcc (redhat, x86_64, 11.3.1) Garbage collector:
Serial GC (max heap size: 80% of RAM) 5 user-specific feature(s)
com.google.api.gax.grpc.nativeimage.GrpcNettyFeature
com.google.api.gax.nativeimage.GoogleJsonClientFeature
com.google.api.gax.nativeimage.OpenCensusFeature
com.oracle.svm.thirdparty.gson.GsonFeature
io.micronaut.core.io.service.ServiceLoaderFeature
[91mNov 18, 2024 10:45:43 AM
com.google.api.gax.nativeimage.NativeImageUtils
registerClassForReflection
WARNING: Failed to find
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ProtocolNegotiators on the
classpath for reflection.


2024-11-25
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version kotlinVer"2.0.21"sion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "2.0.21"
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "2.0.21-1.0.27" 
    id("com.google.cloud.tools.jib") version "3.4.2" 
    id("jacoco")
    id("org.sonarqube") version "4.3.0.3225"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "4.4.4"
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "11.5.1"
    id("io.micronaut.aot") version "4.4.4"
}

micronaut {
    runtime(MicronautRuntime.NETTY)
    version.set("4.7.1")
    testRuntime(MicronautTestRuntime.JUNIT_5)
    processing {
        incremental = true
        annotations("de.foobar")
    }
    aot {
        optimizeServiceLoading = false
        convertYamlToJava = false
        precomputeOperations = true
        cacheEnvironment = true
        optimizeClassLoading = true
        deduceEnvironment = true
        optimizeNetty = true
        replaceLogbackXml = false
        netty {
            enabled = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
...
    // micronaut
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut.gcp:micronaut-gcp-pubsub")
    implementation("io.micronaut.gcp:micronaut-gcp-secret-manager")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kafka:micronaut-kafka")
    implementation("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-jackson")
    implementation("io.micronaut.security:micronaut-security-jwt")
    implementation("io.micronaut.gcp:micronaut-gcp-logging")
}


can you share the pom ?

Added Gradle-Config

ClassNotFoundException comes from mainly not included dependency, your gradle config looks like does not contain hamcrest, does it have only micronaut dependencies, no slf4j or org apache commons ?

I don't think that your question is pointing into the right direction. Is there a way to resolve the not found-classes? One generic way?
